# deploy Openstack via conjure-up in pending

Tags: conjure-up

my lab

- 1 IBM server x3650 Maas
- 4 IBM Svr x3650 Openstack

after to run the deploy of Openstack via conjure-up the task rests in pending and I don't receive any feedback. It's already passed 1hr and nothing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I try to deploy that via Juju the procedure completes all tasks and Openstack is up.

[image]

any idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved that...
it was my error during the configuration of Maas